# Unable to show api response data on screen, next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an OCR API that returns the text from a given image, the data is coming on the client side, visible in the console. But the element is not updating the data.

Here is my Code

```
const onCrop = async () => {
    const cropper = cropperRef.current;
    if (cropper) {
      const canvas = cropper.getCanvas();
      const img_data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
      if (canvas) {

        const getOcrData  =  await fetch("/api/ocr", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ file: img_data }),
          });
         
        const data = await getOcrData.json();
         
        console.log(data.fullTextAnnotation.text);
        const ocrData = data.fullTextAnnotation.text;
        
        return {
          props: { ocrData }
        };
      }
    }
  };
```

And the page element

```
const Guestbook = ({ fallback, ocrData  }) => {

  const [getOcrData, setOcrData] = useState(ocrData);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   let {data} = onCrop();
  //   setOcrData(data); // sets ariaInfo state
  // } 
  // , []);

  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
      <main className="max-w-4xl mx-auto p-4">
        <AppHead />
          
        <div className="flex flex-row content-center">
            <div className="basis-1/2">
            <Example />
            </div>
            <div className="basis-1/2">
              <p>OCR Data</p>
              <p>{getOcrData}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        
      </main>
    </SWRConfig>
  );
};
```

Can anybody help me figuring out what i am doing wrong.

I want data in the **getOcrData**.

[image]

Comment: Your `onCrop` method is returnig a promise, make sure you are resolving that promise first. This thing you are missing in the commented `useEffect` code

Comment: @gauravThakur I am new to nextjs, can you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleAsync = async()=>{
    try{
      
      let res = await onCrop();
      let data = res.props.ocrData 
      setOcrData(data); // sets ariaInfo state
    }catch(e){}
    
    handleAsync();
  }
  } 
 , []);
```

Comment: still the same, not updating the html/element

Comment: I edited my answer , hope this will be ok

Comment: still not working, is everything else okay in the code?